# JavaFX -- Creating multiple panes within a scene

Tags: java, javafx

So I have to make a Zodiac Sign GUI, and we are tasked with having the following:

- a **Label** in the top left, and a **TextField** in the top right (both with padding)
- an exit **Button** in the center of the GUI, along with a clear and find my sign on either side
- and finally, a **Label** in the bottom center prompting the sign

I am utterly confused on how to have this come out, as I am a novice in JavaFX. I believe I would need a branch node along with the root node in order to get this kind of layout. I do not need assistance in instantiating the button, labels etc., mainly confused with how this layout can even work. The code I have now is the following:

```
public class ZodiacGUI extends Application {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane mainPane = new BorderPane();
        mainPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: PINK");
        setupControls(mainPane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane);
        setStage(primaryStage, scene);

    }

    public void setStage(Stage primaryStage, Scene scene) {
        primaryStage.setWidth(500);
        primaryStage.setHeight(200);
        primaryStage.setTitle("What is my Zodiac Sign?");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void setupControls(BorderPane mainPane) {
        Label label = new Label("Enter you birthday formatted as -> mm/dd");
        Button exitButton = new Button();
        Button findSign = new Button();
        Button clear = new Button();
        TextField userInput = new TextField();

        userInput.setPromptText("Enter birthday");
        exitButton.setText("Exit.");
        findSign.setText("Find my sign.");
        clear.setText("Clear.");

        exitButton.setOnAction(e -> System.exit(0));

        mainPane.setLeft(label);
        mainPane.setRight(userInput);
        mainPane.setCenter(exitButton);
        mainPane.setCenter(findSign);
        mainPane.setCenter(clear);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(label, Pos.TOP_LEFT);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(userInput, Pos.TOP_RIGHT);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(exitButton, Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(findSign, Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(clear, Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
    }
}
```

This only outputs one of the buttons out of the three, as I assume it is because the necessary addition of another BorderPane? Here is a drawn out picture of what I would like to come out with:

[image]

Just to clarify, I do not need assistance with the handling of finding the zodiac sign, etc. Mainly need assistance on the layout, as it has stumped me for days. Thank you in advance for helping out a novice to JavaFX :).

Comment: Just three `HBox`s, configured appropriately, in a `VBox` might be enough here.

Comment: Technically you could do all of this with a `StackPane`; The downside is that `StackPane`s don't care about overlapping children; James's suggestion is probably closer, if not identical with the expected solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three rows with diffrent number of children. You can use HBox if row have more than one child.

```
BorderPane mainPane = new BorderPane();
mainPane.setTop(new HBox(topLabel, topField));
mainPane.setCenter(new HBox(centerLabel, centerField, centerButtom));
mainPane.setBottom(bottomCenterButton);
```

If you need more than 3 rows (top, center, bottom section of BorderPane) you can use VBox, where every child is row like:

```
HBox row1 new HBox(child1, child2)
HBox row2 new HBox(child1, child2, child3)
HBox row3 new HBox(child1)
HBox row4 new HBox(child1, child2)
VBox pane = new VBox(row1, row2, row3, row4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a [GridPane](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/javafx/gridpane.html)

```
GridPane grid = new GridPane();
grid.add(label,0,0);
grid.add(userInput,2,0);
grid.add(findSign,0,1);
grid.add(exitButton,1,1);
grid.add(clear,2,1);
```

or use a VBox with BorderPane to help with the layout/alignment

```
BorderPane mainPane, centerPane;

mainPane.setLeft(label);
mainPane.setRight(userInput);

centerPane.setLeft(findSign);
centerPane.setRight(clear);
centerPane.setCenter(exitButton);

BorderPane.setAlignment(label, Pos.LEFT);
BorderPane.setAlignment(userInput, Pos.RIGHT);
BorderPane.setAlignment(exitButton, Pos.CENTER);
BorderPane.setAlignment(findSign, Pos.LEFT);
BorderPane.setAlignment(clear, Pos.RIGHT);

VBox items = new VBox();
items.getChildren().addAll(mainPane, centerPane);
```